# Is there a way to tell initramfs via Grub cmdline to open specified device with cryptsetup?

Tags: debian, boot, initramfs, cryptsetup

I have a Debian setup where rootfs is on a btrfs subvolume which is on a lvm partition which is on a luks partition which is on `disk-A2` (`disk-A||disk-A2||luks||lvm||btrfs||rootfs`)

I just copied my btrfs subvolume to `disk-B2||luks||mylvm||btrfs||my-new-subvolume`, changed appropriate lines in `my-new-subvolume/etc/fstab` and `my-new-subvolume/etc/crypttab`, changed appropriate `grub.cfg` lines (the UUID's) and rebooted.

Unfortunately initramfs is unable to determine that it has to try to open `disk-B` with `cryptsetup`. It continuously shows some messages and drops me into the `initramfs shell`.

I also tried to replace old uuid's with new one in `initramfs/conf/conf.d/cryptroot` but there is no luck.

How can I tell initramfs that it has to try to open `disk-B` via Grub cmdline?

Comment: When you're dropped at the `(initramfs)` shell, use `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/disk-B2 crypt` (or similar) to decrypt your disk, then activate your VG via `vgchange -ay`. Exit the shell, the initramfs should find your root FS now (if the `root=` argument on your kernel command line is correct) and start the boot process. One booted, run `update-initramfs -u` and reboot to see it that helped.